# MLR doubt regarding invariance of predicted values

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, linear-model

in the model  $ Y= X\beta +\epsilon  $
when they say the predicted value of y is invariant to full rank linear tranformation on xi's . what does it mean . ?

does it mean that any linear transformation on X  that doesn't change its column rank will give same predicted values ?

Comment: in the statement : the following are also invariant to changes of scale on y as well as on x's (but not to a joint linear transformation on y and x's) .t statistics , F statistics , $ R^2 $ :,.,., does it mean that changes only on either on  x's or y's can be done at time ,. simultaneous scale change will create trouble ?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, it does not matter for fitted values and residuals if we change the units of measurement of $X$.

Consider transforming $X$ by some invertible $k\times k$ matrix $A$, $XA$ (e.g., change months of schooling to years and meters to centimeters when explaining wages).

This is seen as follows,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_{XA}&:=&XA\bigl((XA)'XA\bigr)^{-1}(XA)'\\
&=&XA\bigl(A'X'XA\bigr)^{-1}A'X'\\
&=&XAA^{-1}(X'X)^{-1}(A')^{-1}A'X'\\
&=&P_{X}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @Christoph Hanck  $ thanks, $ , so they meant , predicted values are invariant to changes on scales of Xi's,,,,. please also explain the additional question mentioned as a comment  below the question

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you would transform $X$ to $X'$ like: $X'=A^{T}X$, where $A$ is *not of full rank*, then you would effectively be dropping information in $X$.

Depending on your data and fitting method, this may well result in different predictions for $Y$ after fitting.

As an illustration, consider the situation where $A$ has not full rank, which means that at least 1 of its rows can be written as a linear combination of the others.

So, we could write for example: $A=BA'$, where

$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 0 & 1 & \, & 0\\ \vdots & \, & \, & \, & \, \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$

note the last row, which is $0$.

Substituting this in $X'=A^{T}X$ leads to $X'=\left(BA'\right)^{T}X=A'^{T}B^{T}X$, which will drop the last feature in the data $X$.